# Frame animation in android

Tags: android

I have one application in which I have two images. The first image is a young boy with balloons in his hands, and the second image is of a single ballon that is aligned with the balloons of first image.

When we click on that second ballon image, I want that balloon to go to the top of the picture, as it does in the air. But I have no idea how to create this animation. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweened animation is handled by this package: android.view.animation.

Here's what you want to do, basically: put a Listener on your image, that launches the tween.

It's a simple move from bottom to top, is easy to handle with the translateanimation class.
Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html .